# Does $\Delta (g(t, \cdot) *f) = \Delta g(t, \cdot) *f$ hold if $f$ is bounded continuous without compact support?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, laplacian

We consider the heat kernel
$$
g :\mathbb R_{>0} \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, (t, x) \mapsto \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}} \exp \bigg ( - \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \bigg ).
$$

I would like to verify that

> **Theorem** If $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function with compact support, then
> $$
> \Delta (g(t, \cdot) *f) =  \Delta g(t, \cdot) *f. 
> $$

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Does the theorem hold if $f$ is bounded continuous without compact support?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

We have $*$ is [continuous bilinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667916/the-map-fg-is-uniformly-continuous) and $\Delta  = \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k}$. So it suffices to prove that
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} (g(t, \cdot) *f) =  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, \cdot) *f.
$$

First, we will prove
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (g(t, \cdot) *f) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, \cdot) *f. \tag{1}
$$

Fix $x \in \mathbb R^d$. Let $K$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R$ that contains the support of $f$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (g(t, \cdot) *f) (x) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \int_{\mathbb R^d} g(t, x-y) f(y) \, \mathrm d y \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \int_{K} g(t, x-y) f(y) \, \mathrm d y.
\end{align*}
$$

Fix $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Let $B(x, \varepsilon)$ be the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$. By [Leibniz integral rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706399/a-proof-of-leibniz-integral-rule), it suffices to prove
$$
\sup \{g(t, z-y) |f(y)| :  y \in  K, z \in B(x, \varepsilon)\} < \infty. \tag{2}
$$

We have $g(t, \cdot)$ is smooth and $f$ is continuous, so $(y, z) \mapsto g(t, z-y) |f(y)|$ is continuous. On the other hand, $\overline{K \times B(x, \varepsilon)}$ is compact, so (2) is indeed true. It remains to prove
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, \cdot) *f \right ) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, \cdot) *f. \tag{3}
$$

Notice that $g(t, \cdot)$ is smooth, so $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, \cdot)$ is smooth. Then (3) follows from the same argument that we used to prove (1). This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat kernel is so nice that the theorem holds for bounded measurable $f$.

---

We have $*$ is [continuous bilinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667916/the-map-fg-is-uniformly-continuous) and $\Delta  = \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k}$, so it suffices to prove that
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} (g(t, \cdot) *f) =  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, \cdot) *f.
$$

Notice that
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, x) &= \frac{-x_k}{2t} g(t, x), \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, x) &= \frac{x_k^2-2t}{4t^2} g(t, x).
\end{align*}
$$

First, we will prove
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} (g(t, \cdot) *f) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, \cdot) *f,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \int_{\mathbb R^d} g(t, x-y) f(y) \, \mathrm d y = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, x-y) f(y) \, \mathrm d y.
\tag{1}
$$

Fix $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Let $B(x, \varepsilon)$ be the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$. By [Leibniz integral rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706399/a-proof-of-leibniz-integral-rule), it suffices to prove that there is an integrable map $\theta:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\bigg| f(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k} g(t, z-y) \bigg | \le \theta (y)
\quad \forall z \in B(x, \varepsilon), y \in \mathbb R^d.
\tag{2}
$$

Indeed,
$$
\begin{align*}
\bigg| f(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k} g(t, z-y) \bigg | &= \frac{|y_k-z_k| }{2t} g(t, y-z) |f(y)|\\
&\le \frac{(|z| + |y|) \|f\|_\infty}{2t} g(t, y-z) \\
&\overset{(\star)}{\le} 2^{d/2}e^{|z|^2/(4t)} \|f\|_\infty \frac{|z| + |y|}{2t} g(2t, y),
\end{align*}
$$
where $(\star)$ follows from inequality (2.3) of the paper [Euler scheme for density dependent stochastic differential equations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022039620306008) by Hao/Röckner/Zhang. Let
$$
\alpha := 2^{d/2} \|f\|_\infty \sup_{z \in B(x, \varepsilon)}  e^{|z|^2/(4t)} \frac{|z|+1}{2t} < \infty.
$$

Let $\theta (y) := \alpha (1+|y|) g(2t, y)$ for $y \in \mathbb R^d$. Then $\|\theta\|_{L^1} < \infty$ and (2) is indeed true. It remains to prove
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, \cdot) *f \right ) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, \cdot) *f,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} g(t, x-y) f (y) \, \mathrm d y = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2_k} g(t, x-y) f (y) \, \mathrm d y.
\end{align*}
\tag{3}
$$

Indeed, (3) follows from the same argument that we used to prove (1). This completes the proof.